# Using Mailhandler commands in individual emails (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, feeds, emails

My business objective is to create nodes from emails and apply existing taxonomy terms based on individual email content. I've installed and set up Mailhandler (7.x-2.10) in a fresh Drupal 7.38 install (with Feeds and other dependencies). It's connected to the right mailbox and is fetching and parsing email correctly. I've read the readme.txt and install.txt and lots of commentary elsewhere. But what I can't seem to do is deploy commands from the emails being parsed. Can I simply create commands in the "Available commands" field of the "Settings for Mailhandler IMAP stream parser" and then map them to my available fields in the "Mapping for Node processor"? (for example, I add "source" to the "Available commands" field and then map it to a "source" taxonomy in Drupal; every email coming in contains a "source: value" combination at the top of the email). This doesn't seem to work (except with the "status" command that was already written into the parser). Do I need to create a custom command parser in order to get commands from email to work?